# Uploading JSONObject to Iris CouchDb in Android

Tags: java, android, json, couchdb, iriscouch

I´m currently working on an app and having my problems with uploading a JSONObject to my Iris CouchDb. But I can´t get it to work.

This is the code I´m using right now:

```
private class MyHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://dbname.iriscouch.com/dbname");

        try {
            // Add your data
            JSONObject jsonDoc = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonDoc.put("name", "test");
                jsonDoc.put("autor", "test author");
                jsonDoc.put("rundgangnr", "1");
                jsonDoc.put("latitude", 58.0);
                jsonDoc.put("longitude", 7.88);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // end try
            String body = jsonDoc.toString();
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "utf-8");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream result = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

In onCreate I do this to execute the function:

```
new MyHttpPost().execute();
```

When I run the app, there are no errors but nothing gets uploaded. So there isn´t any change in the database.

Am I using the wrong URL to upload it on Iris or is there something wrong with the code? I´m new to Android development and really would appreciate your help as I have been struggling with this for days now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use `https://accountname.iriscouch.com/dbname` rather than `https://dbname.iriscouch.com/dbname`.

Also, if the request throws an IOException, your app will be silently swallowing the error so you might not be seeing it.